# Conversion from string "insert into reciptdetails(recip" to type "integer" is not vaild)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

geting the recipt id from the database

```
        SQL = "select max(reciptid) as MAXID from recipts where 1"
        Dim CMD2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        CMD2.Connection = MyConnection
        CMD2.Transaction = MyTransaction
        CMD2.CommandText = SQL
        Dim ReciptID As Long = CMD2.ExecuteScalar()
        CMD2.Dispose()
```

insert the details of the reciept

```
         Dim I As Integer
        For I = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
            'get the values first


            Dim Barcode As String = DataGridView2.Rows(I).Cells(0).Value
            Dim ItemBuyPrice As Decimal = DataGridView2.Rows(I).Cells(2).Value
            Dim ItemSellPrice As Decimal = DataGridView2.Rows(I).Cells(3).Value
            Dim ItemCount As Integer = DataGridView2.Rows(I).Cells(4).Value

            Dim CMD3 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            SQL = "insert into reciptdetails (reciptid, barcode, itemcount, itembuyprice, itemsellprice) values (:0      ,:1       ,:2        ,:3         ,:4        )"
            CMD3.Connection = MyConnection
            CMD3.Transaction = MyTransaction
            CMD3.CommandType = SQL
            CMD3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":0", ReciptID)
            CMD3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":1", Barcode)
            CMD3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":2", ItemCount)
            CMD3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":3", ItemBuyPrice)
            CMD3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":4", ItemSellPrice)

            CMD3.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CMD3.Dispose()
```

when i run this query at catch running the SQL command i get this error
[image]

is there anything wrong with the query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your error:

```
CMD3.CommandType = SQL
```

[`OleDbCommand.CommandType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a [CommandType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx) value, not a String.

You probably meant to write:

```
CMD3.CommandText = SQL
```

I strongly recommend to [**turn on `Option Strict`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2454552/87698), which allows you to catch such errors at compile-time rather than at run-time.

Comment: OMG thankyou so much ive been at it for 3 hrs now THANKYOU SO MUCH such a silly mistake

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On` and then issues like that will be detected at compile time, i.e. when you write the code, rather than at run time.